Why list.insert(-1,any value) does not replace the last value in python?
Tried to use insert method to add a last value but it always go the 2nd last value
list = [10,3,5,100,7,9]

list_1=(list insert(-1,'hello'))

print(list_1)

Expected result: [10,3,5,100,7,9,'hello']
Actual result: [10,3,5,100,7,'hello',9]

That is correct. The insert funtion inserts the new value before the element indicated. And element -1 is the last item in the list. See Data Structures - More on Lists.

Consider using the Python append method instead, as it automatically adds items to the end of the list
list = [10,3,5,100,7,9]
list.append('hello')
print(list)

which gives

[10, 3, 5, 100, 7, 9, 'hello']

or you can also simply put the index of the place right after where you want to insert the data into, on this case being the same as the length of the list:
list = [10,3,5,100,7,9]
list.insert(len(list), 'hello')
print(list)

which will also yield the same results. For more info on the append method go here

insert is adding a value in a specific location and shifts right the value that is currently there. If you want to add value to the end of the list use
lst.insert(len(lst), 'hello')

Which gives the same behavior as
lst.append('hello')

